# Chrome Extension - On some websites `web_accessible_resources` are prevented from showing

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension, written in React, and attaches itself to the page using a shadow DOM element. Inside I am loading the extension's logo and a content stylesheet.

However, it was reported that the extension was not loading properly and have pinpointed that any resource from `web_accessible_resources` (e.g. chrome-extensions://...) were being unmounted from the page on certain sites (e.g. https://www.skechers.com/).

In a work-around we ended up serving the content from our CDN, which works fine. Still wondered if anyone knew why this didn't work on a few sites.

I also wrote code to see if it removes the stylesheet and then loads the CDN version, just to test it out.

```
const onStylesLoad = (loaded) => {
    const sheet = loaded.target.sheet
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!sheet.ownerNode) {
        console.log('FALLBACK', sheet);
        setFallback('https://cdn.***/themes/browserExtension/content.css');
      }
    }, 1000);
}

// And later in the render...

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' onLoad={onStylesLoad} href={browser.runtime.getURL('content.css')} />
{fallback && <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href={fallback} />}
```

The extensions stylesheet *does* load, but then is immediately unmounted, which is how I am able to detect a moment later that the ownerNode is null (onLoad its attached to the link).

I am fine with the work-around, it just irks me that packaging any content is made moot, since we have too point it to a CDN regardless.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in JS so it triggers right when the link element is appended, then set a DOM breakpoint in devtools on this added element, and see what removes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the css files locally, rather than from a CDN, you could minify the css files, then store them as a string in your js files and insert them into the page by creating a style element on document ready. I guess they probably wouldn't be able to reference the local images though, but it seems you're not able to anyway